# Please help me I cannot start Intent from list fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listfragment, listactivity

I have ListFragment and I want to start new activity from each list by using onListItemClick() but she n click on list the application always crash stop working please kindly see my code bellow
please help thanks you.

OldTestamentFragment.java

```
package com.cambobox.slidemenu.model.model;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cambobox.slidemenu.R;
import com.cambobox.slidemenu.model.adapter.OldtestamentAdapter;
public class OldTestamentFragment extends ListFragment {
String[] old_testament_list;
Typeface font;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    {
//List view with custom adapter
    old_testament_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.old_testament_list);
        setListAdapter(new OldtestamentAdapter(getActivity(),old_testament_list));
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),Chapter.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            break;
            .......
            .......
        }
    }
}
```

Chapter.java

```
package com.cambobox.slidemenu.model.model;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.cambobox.slidemenu.R;
import com.cambobox.slidemenu.model.adapter.ChapterAdapter;


public class Chapter extends ListActivity {
    String[] chapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        chapter = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.genesis);
        setListAdapter(new ChapterAdapter(this,chapter));
   }
}
```

chapter_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chapter_list"
    android:text="@+id/chapter_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

ChapterAdapter.java

```
package com.cambobox.slidemenu.model.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cambobox.slidemenu.R;
import com.cambobox.slidemenu.model.model.Chapter;

public class ChapterAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
public final Context context;
public final String[] value;
Typeface font;
public ChapterAdapter(Context context, String[] value){
    super(context, R.layout.chapter_activity,value);
    this.context = context;
    this.value = value;
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"font/khmerbibleregular.ttf");
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chapter_activity,parent,false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.chapter_list);
    textView.setTypeface(font);
    textView.setTextSize(30);
    textView.setText(value[position]);
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Logcat

```
05-21 15:13:02.838    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string:    TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:02.858    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 25K, 2% free 9358K/9508K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
05-21 15:13:02.868    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 11.068MB for 1992656-byte allocation
05-21 15:13:02.878    3890-3899/com.cambobox.slidemenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 2% free 11301K/11456K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
05-21 15:13:02.918    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 2% free 11298K/11456K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
05-21 15:13:02.928    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 12.962MB for 1992656-byte allocation
05-21 15:13:02.938    3890-3899/com.cambobox.slidemenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 13244K/13404K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
05-21 15:13:02.968    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:02.978    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:02.978    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:02.978    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:02.988    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:02.988    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:02.988    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:02.998    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:02.998    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:03.008    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:03.008    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:03.008    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:07.312    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-21 15:13:07.312    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41544ba8)
05-21 15:13:07.322    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cambobox.slidemenu, PID: 3890
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.cambobox.slidemenu/com.cambobox.slidemenu.model.model.Testing}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1541)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3957)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3932)
        at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1054)
        at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1033)
        at com.cambobox.slidemenu.model.model.OldTestamentFragment.onListItemClick(OldTestamentFragment.java:42)
        at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:160)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 15:13:10.345    3890-3890/com.cambobox.slidemenu I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 3890 SIG: 9
05-21 15:13:16.241    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu I/Adreno-EGL﹕   <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build:    I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
05-21 15:13:16.261    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-21 15:13:16.361    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 163K, 3% free 9330K/9524K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
05-21 15:13:21.536    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string:  TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:21.556    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 23K, 2% free 9357K/9524K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
05-21 15:13:21.556    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 11.067MB for 1992656-byte allocation
05-21 15:13:21.566    3940-3949/com.cambobox.slidemenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 2% free 11301K/11472K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
05-21 15:13:21.606    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 2% free 11299K/11472K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
05-21 15:13:21.606    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 12.962MB for 1992656-byte allocation
05-21 15:13:21.616    3940-3949/com.cambobox.slidemenu D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 13244K/13420K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
05-21 15:13:21.636    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:21.636    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:21.646    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:21.646    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:21.646    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:21.646    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:21.646    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:21.656    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:21.656    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:21.656    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:21.656    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:21.666    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f080043}
05-21 15:13:25.430    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-21 15:13:25.430    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41544ba8)
05-21 15:13:25.430    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cambobox.slidemenu, PID: 3940
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.cambobox.slidemenu/com.cambobox.slidemenu.model.model.Testing}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1541)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3957)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3932)
        at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1054)
        at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1033)
        at com.cambobox.slidemenu.model.model.OldTestamentFragment.onListItemClick(OldTestamentFragment.java:42)
        at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:160)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 15:13:28.313    3940-3940/com.cambobox.slidemenu I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 3940 SIG: 9
```

Comment: have you declared Testing activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Read it more than once `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.cambobox.slidemenu/com.cambobox.slidemenu.model.model.Testing}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.cambobox.slidemenu/com.cambobox.slidemenu.model.model.Testing};
>
> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Just copy pasted. You need to declare your activity in manifest.